# Java/WildFly/MongoDB/JAAS - Authentication always returns 403 - Forbidden

Tags: java, mongodb, jaas, form-authentication, wildfly-8

I've created a custom LoginModule to authenticate the users present in mongoDB collections. In my case, I need one Role per page...
I've already used JAAS authentication with JSF, but in this case, it's not working as expected... It's always returns 403 error (Forbidden). The mapping of the URLs apparently is OK.

That's my pages hierarchy:

- app <-root

  - pages

    - my protected pages (one role per page)
  - login.html
  - login_error.html
  - index.html

Follow my configurations:

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>nfceSecurityDomain</security-domain>
    <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <form-login-config>
          <form-login-page>/app/login.html</form-login-page>
          <form-error-page>/app/login_error.html</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
   <role-name>VISUALIZAR_NOTAS</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
   <role-name>GESTAO_CERTIFICADO</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
   <role-name>GESTAO_EMPRESA</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
   <role-name>DOWNLOAD_XML</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
   <role-name>INUTILIZACAO</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>index</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/app/index.html</url-pattern>
         <http-method>POST</http-method>
         <http-method>GET</http-method>
         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>VISUALIZAR_NOTAS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>orderList</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/app/pages/orderlist.html</url-pattern>
         <http-method>POST</http-method>
         <http-method>GET</http-method>
         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>VISUALIZAR_NOTAS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>certificateConfigurations</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/app/pages/certifiedlist.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>GESTAO_CERTIFICADO</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>enterpriseConfigurations</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/app/pages/enterpriselist.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>GESTAO_EMPRESA</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>xmlDownload</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/app/pages/orderdownload.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>DOWNLOAD_XML</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>invalidate</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/app/pages/orderInvalidate.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>INUTILIZACAO</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="nfceSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="br.com.ciss.nfce.security.JAASLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

And here is my implementation of LoginModule, to get the user and roles from MongoDB:

```
public class JAASLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JAASLoginModule.class);

    private Subject subject;
    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
    private Map sharedState;
    private Map options;

    private boolean succeeded = false;
    private boolean commitSucceeded = false;

    private String username = null;
    private String _idUser = "";
    private char[] password = null;

    private Principal userPrincipal = null;
    private Principal passwordPrincipal = null;

    private ConnectionMongoUtil connectionMongoUtil;

    public JAASLoginModule() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
            Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
        this.sharedState = sharedState;
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {

        if (callbackHandler == null) {
            throw new LoginException("Error: no CallbackHandler available "
                    + "to garner authentication information from the user");
        }
        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("username");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password: ", false);

        try {
            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            username = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
            password = ((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword();

            if (username == null || password == null) {
                LOG.error("Callback handler does not return login data properly");
                throw new LoginException(
                        "Callback handler does not return login data properly");
            }

            if (isValidUser()) { // validate user.
                succeeded = true;
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        if (succeeded == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            userPrincipal = new JAASUserPrincipal(username);
            if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(userPrincipal)) {
                subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);
                LOG.debug("User principal added:" + userPrincipal);
            }
            passwordPrincipal = new JAASPasswordPrincipal(new String(password));
            if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(passwordPrincipal)) {
                subject.getPrincipals().add(passwordPrincipal);
                LOG.debug("Password principal added: " + passwordPrincipal);
            }

            List<String> roles = getRoles();
            for (String role : roles) {
                Principal rolePrincipal = new JAASRolePrincipal(role);
                if (!subject.getPrincipals().contains(rolePrincipal)) {
                    subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
                    LOG.debug("Role principal added: " + rolePrincipal);
                }
            }

            commitSucceeded = true;
            LOG.info("Login subject were successfully populated with principals and roles");
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
        if (succeeded == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (succeeded == true && commitSucceeded == false) {
            succeeded = false;
            username = null;
            if (password != null) {
                password = null;
            }
            userPrincipal = null;
        } else {
            logout();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
        subject.getPrincipals().remove(userPrincipal);
        succeeded = false;
        succeeded = commitSucceeded;
        username = null;
        if (password != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
                password[i] = ' ';
                password = null;
            }
        }
        userPrincipal = null;
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isValidUser() throws LoginException {

        try {
            BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject();
            search.put("email", username);
            connectionMongoUtil = new ConnectionMongoUtil();
            DBObject user = connectionMongoUtil.getCollection("User").findOne(search);

            if (user == null){
                LOG.debug("USUÁRIO NÃO LOCALIZADO!");
                return false;
            }else{
                if ( new String(password).equals(user.get("password"))){
                    _idUser = user.get("_id").toString();
                    return true;
                }else{
                    LOG.debug("SENHA INVÁLIDA PARA O USUÁRIO " + username);
                }
            }

            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error when loading user " + username + " from the database \n", e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns list of roles assigned to authenticated user.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private List<String> getRoles() {
        BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject();
        search.put("_idUser", _idUser);
        DBObject userModules = connectionMongoUtil.getCollection("UserModules").findOne(search);
        String jsonArrayModules = userModules.get("_idModules").toString();

        String[] modules = null;
        try {
            modules = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonArrayModules, String[].class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> modulesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String _idModule : modules) {
            DBObject module = connectionMongoUtil.getCollection("Module").findOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(_idModule)));
            if (module != null){
                modulesList.add(module.get("name").toString());
            }
        }

        return modulesList;
    }
}
```

I have added the following property in standalone.xml, to see the logs generated by JAAS, and don't have any error log...

```
<logger category="org.jboss.security">
    <level name="ALL"/>
</logger>
```

In my MongoDB collections, I've added all the roles to my user, and when I try to login, I can log in, but all the pages are locked, returning the 403 error.

Anybody can help me?
Maybe it's just a little detail causing the 403 error...

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual MongoDB query being used and the return value? If you're not sure where to add the debug info in JAAS, you could try using the MongoDB [database profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) at a level of 2 (all queries, instead of only slow queries).

Comment: Hi guy, thanks for your answer... I think the problem is not about mongoDB queries, because I put the user and the roles fixed in JAASLoginModule, and the same error happens.

I think the error is in a JBoss configuration...

Comment: I've changed this project to make some tests and I shared it in my google drive... In the google drive, there's the project (eclipse), the standalone.xml file for wildfly and the logs generated when I tried to access the pages... 
 
In the project there's two implementations of LoginModule, but I use just the JAASLoginModule.
 
If someone can help me, I will be very grateful...


https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_GgtF8zczPWbnV2cmVxZDlvQ3c&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to resolve this situation is change JAAS by Spring Security :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploy your module in wildfly
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/configuring-a-mongodb-login-module

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have time to do this in my work. When I have some time I will do this test and then I let you know about the result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread, but still without a good solution.

I had the very same problem ...

**Some context**: 
I had a "healthy" java web app using JAAS (implementing javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule directly) running smoothly on Tomcat7.
Then a customer requirement came in the scene: "It must run on JBoss 7.1.1"
WTF? Even the minor version and patch!?!

**Hands On**: 
So I did all the configuration, had some drawbacks with Java 8 code and JAX-RS, but this is another story, in the end My App was deployed successfully in JBoss 7.1.1.

**Problem**:
I could see in the console that login was successfull, but all the requests were returning HTTP 403.

While debugging all Principals (CallerPrincipal and UserRoles) were OK.

Also, I have a single abstract BaseServlet for orchestration and which all the requests should traverse, but HTTP 403 ocurred before reach it...

**Solution**:
So I've noticed that all JBoss documentation regarding JAAS advise developers to extend their customized LoginModules, so I started digging.

The org.jboss.security.auth.spi.AbstractServerLoginModule uses what they call "JBossSX standard Subject usage pattern of storing identities and roles".

I've not gone that deep to explain the pattern, but I've realyzed the 'JBossWebRealm' which wraps the authentication process in the container side expects an java.security.acl.Group implementation with name "Roles" containing all Principals (CallerPrincipal and UserRoles) as members (*The Membership Of The JAASRealm*).

This object is used for security check.

End of story, I've added this method to my LoginModule implementation:

```
public boolean commit() throws LoginException {

    // some validation code here

    Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();

    // ensure principals contains (CallerPrincipal and UserRoles)

    createRolesGroup(principals);

    return true;
}

private void createRolesGroup(Set<Principal> principals) {

    // Thee java.security.acl.Group implementation
    SecurityGroup rolesGroup = new SecurityGroup("Roles");

    Iterator<Principal> iter = principals.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Object principal = iter.next();
        if(!(principal instanceof Group)){
        rolesGroup.addMember((Principal)principal);
    }

    principals.add(rolesGroup);
}
```

And works like charm.

Hope it helps.